# maxTwo Implementation Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

> Given a list of integers `xs`, find the two largest values and return
> them in a pair (largest first). Largest duplicates should be preserved
> (included) in the output. Do not modify the original list.

This is what I came up with but it did not quite give the correct answer. Here is the code and the second section is the terminal run:

```
minInt = minBound :: Int

maxTwoHelper1 :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)
maxTwoHelper1 (x : xs) = maxTwoHelper2 minInt minInt xs

maxTwoHelper2 :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> (Int, Int)
maxTwoHelper2 first second [] = (first, second)
maxTwoHelper2 first second (x : xs)
  | x >= first = maxTwoHelper2 x second xs
  | x >= second = maxTwoHelper2 first x xs
  | otherwise = maxTwoHelper2 first second xs
```

```
*Main> maxTwoHelper1 [1,0,-1]
(0,-1)
```

Comment: What does "Do not modify the original list" mean?

Answer (score 3):

Your `maxTwoHelper1` is dropping the `x`, it should consider all elements, so:

```
maxTwoHelper1 :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)
maxTwoHelper1 xs = maxTwoHelper2 minBound minBound xs
```

Your `maxTwoHelper2` also contains an error: in case `x >= first`, `x` is the largest, and `first` the second largest, so:

```
maxTwoHelper2 :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> (Int, Int)
maxTwoHelper2 first second [] = (first, second)
maxTwoHelper2 first second (x : xs)
  | x >= first = maxTwoHelper2 x first xs  -- 🖘 first as second largest
  | x >= second = maxTwoHelper2 first x xs
  | otherwise = maxTwoHelper2 first second xs
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use `sortBy`:

```hs
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Ord (Down (..))

maxTwo :: (Ord a, Bounded a) => [a] -> (a, a)
maxTwo xs = case sortBy (compare `on` Down) xs of
  [] -> (minBound, minBound)
  [biggest] -> (biggest, minBound)
  biggest : second : _ -> (biggest, second)

-- Or, if you don't mind "can't happen" errors:

maxTwo :: (Ord a, Bounded a) => [a] -> (a, a)
maxTwo xs = case sortBy (compare `on` Down) $ minBound : minBound : xs of
  biggest : second : _ -> (biggest, second)
  _ -> error "Impossible!"
```

This is efficient because the `sortBy` function uses an *incremental* sort (it happens to be a lazy bottom-up merge sort, but there are also incremental versions of heapsort and quicksort available). It only takes time `O(n + k * log k)` to get the first `k` elements of the result of sorting `n` elements. [See these slides](http://logic.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/%7Esakaguchi/slides/haskell-day-2021.pdf) for a proof. So getting the `k` biggest elements for any *fixed* `k` (in this case 2) takes `O(n)` time.

Comment: is there a _non_-incremental heapsort?

Comment: @WillNess, sure, just pick a heap implementation that doesn't offer `fromList` in `O(n)` time.

Comment: wouldn't it make such a thing to _not_ be a proper heap at all, then? I thought that to be the one distinguishing feature of heaps a.o.t. search trees, say. that's what I meant with the previous comment, anyway.

Comment: @WillNess, who knows? I think of a heap generally as a priority queue based on heap-ordered trees, but you'll probably find three definitions for every two people who write about data structures.